# Purpose of conditional jump after zeroing a register

Tags: assembly, compilation, x86

I encountered a piece of x86 assembler something like this:

```
  push eax
  xor eax, eax
  je label1
  add esp, 4
label1:
  pop eax
```

As far as I can tell, the `xor` instruction will always leave ZF set which in turn makes the `je` always fire. Is this piece of code equivalent to a `nop`?
Would a compiler ever generate this? If yes, why?

Comment: There may be other code jumping directly at `je` or `add` instruction, skipping the `xor`. But it looks unlikely, and it looks unlikely some high level language compiler would produce such code.

Comment: @Ped7g nope, no other code jumps into this snippet.

Comment: Then from execution point of view it is useless. (It may still form some binary data through instruction opcodes, so maybe some other part is reading those `xor/je/add` instructions as data). It may be also result of code modification by somebody else afterwards, without source. Or whatever, hard to tell - in assembly the whole binary and target platform forms **complete context**. You may be missing some tiny detail.

Comment: Instead of `xor eax,eax`, a `je` after a `or eax,eax` would make sense, but then the rest (`add esp,4` and `pop eax`) wouldn't. It looks very much as if this code used to be different and was modified for some reason.

Comment: Where did you encounter this? Can you provide some context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions directly:

> Is this piece of code equivalent to a `nop`?

No. It does change flags (by `xor eax,eax`), and it does set memory at `[esp-4]` to original `eax` value. (I mean the total machine state difference between first and last instruction)

Plus it forms in memory different opcodes than other forms of `nop` (in case these opcodes are also read as data somewhere else, for example checksumming as anti-tamper measure, etc).

And the internal CPU state may be modified much more than by `nop`, some branch prediction data did very likely change due to `je`, and the memory write to stack area may have triggered further changes to state of cache (unlikely, as that part of memory is probably used extensively by instructions around this part). And it will have different timing than `nop`.

> Would a compiler ever generate this? If yes, why?

I don't think so, flags are rarely used over bigger amount of instructions by compilers, and to set memory in unstable stack area the `move [esp-4],eax` would be used, but in the first place it's unlikely the compiler would have need to set value there.